# .htaccess 301 Redirect failure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I have the following code:

```
# 301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 www.website.com www.website.com/shop
```

I want the site to automatically redirect anyone visiting www.website.com or website.com to www.website.com/shop, I can't get it to work, can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://www.website.com/shop
```

Note that the regex portion does not include (and cannot include) protocol and hostname. The new URL can include protocol and hostname (or it can just begin with `/` in Apache >= 2.2.6).

Note that `Redirect` (not used in the above example) uses prefix matching -- any request *beginning with* the specified path will match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a permanent (301) redirect of your root folder `'/'`:

```
Redirect 301 / www.website.com/shop
```

A temporary redirect (302):

```
Redirect 302 / www.website.com/shop
```

301 and 302 are different domain redirects, within the same domain you can do:

```
Redirect / www.website.com/shop
```